# django error : i m run http://127.0.0.1:8000/ get error

Tags: django

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^blog/
^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

Comment: Please give more details and properly format your question (currently, it's totally unreadable). As a minimum, we need your urlpatterns.

Answer (score 0):

Once to run manage.py runserver, the cmd should open and to to your web browser type http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ it will work.

Answer (score -2):

Try http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/, as the error message said.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/  get error like   TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/
blog.html, blog/post_list.html

Comment: That's another question.

Comment: thats my urls.py                                                                                                       from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$', blog.index_view, name ='home'),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]

Comment: Sorry, it was example with poor explanation and I removed it.